# Можно ли быстро привести все аргументы класса к виду self.<аргумент> в функции __init__(self)?

Tags: python, классы, pygame

Сейчас я пишу свой класс кнопки в pygame для своей игры. На вход класс получает кучу аргументов. Очень неудобно писать для каждого выражение вида `self.arg = arg`. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ привести например список аргументов к виду self.arg?

Например, есть такая ситуация:

```
def __init__(self, surface, color, x, y, length, height, width, text, text_color, font_size):
    self.surface = surface
    self.color = color
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, [self.x, self.y, 50, 50])
```

А хочется так:

```
def __init__(self, args): #args - список с элементами surface, color, x и y
    super_function(args)
    pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, [self.x, self.y, 50, 50])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно подобным образом поступить, к примеру, через `*args, **kwargs`. Тогда в `self.args` будет лежать кортеж переменных, а в `self,kwargs` — словарь

```
class Dummy:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs


dummy = Dummy(1, 2, 3, 5, a = 1.2, b = 1.2, c = 1.3)
print(dummy.args)  # (1, 2, 3, 5)
print(dummy.kwargs)  # {'a': 1.2, 'b': 1.2, 'c': 1.3}
```

А можно чуть усложнить и сделать через магию установки атрибутов `__setattr__()`, если нужны атрибуты, но лень много строк набивать.

```
class Dummy:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        attr = ['surface', 'color', 'x', 'y']
        for ia, a in enumerate(attr):
            self.__setattr__(a, args[ia])
        self.args = args  # Оставил на всякий случай
        self.kwargs = kwargs


dummy = Dummy(1, 2, 3, 5)
print(dummy.surface)  # 1
print(dummy.color)  # 2
print(dummy.x)  # 3
print(dummy.y)  # 5
```

В списке `attr` задаем необходимые атрибуты, под которые потом из кортежа `args` вытаскиваем значения и применяем `__setattr__`. Нужно учитывать, что в `args` может быть больше параметров, т.к. он ловит все введенные параметры, на количество которых нет ограничения, тогда можно либо весь кортеж `args` сохранить, либо обрезать его потом.

Если же параметров будет меньше, то получим отличное от обычного `TypeError` (с сообщением о нехватке параметров) исключение в виде `IndexError`. Его можно при желании обернуть в `TypeError`.

Comment: Да, второй вариант - именно то, что мне было нужно. Спасибо за ответ и потраченное вами время.