# Как использовать дескрипторы при большом количестве атрибутов в классе

Tags: python, ооп

К примеру есть класс (прямоугольник), который хранит в себе 2 координаты. Для чтения и обновления значений используется дескрипторы (класс RectangleValue).

Код выглядит так:

```
class RectangleValue:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.__name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.__name]

    def __set__(self, instance, amount):
        instance.__dict__[self.__name] = amount

class Rectangle:

    width = RectangleValue()
    heigth = RectangleValue()

    def __init__(self, width, heigth):
        self.width = width
        self.heigth = heigth
```

Но что делать если атрибутов будет не 2, а 10 и больше, тогда инструкция foo = RectangleValue() для каждого атрибута будет фактически дублированием кода.

Есть ли какие-то более правильные реализации данного кода для большого количества атрибутов?

Comment: По одной строке на поле объекта - это нормально. 10-20 полей объекта тоже нормально. Какую оптимизацию вы хотите? Все в одну строку?

Comment: @insolor В объекте в принципе можно в три строки поля заполнить из аргументов.

Comment: @AndyPavlov Поделитесь способом? Ради спортивного интереса

Comment: через `self.__setattr__()` в `__init__`. Второй вариант в моем ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306406/229113

Comment: Вообще ничего кроме чего-то подобного `exec('heigth = RectangleValue()')` на уровне класса не приходит в голову. Но это как-то совсем не ванильно

Comment: @AndyPavlov Через `self.__setattr__()` дескрипторы не работают. (Может я что-то не так сделал?)

Comment: @nomnoms12 не пробовал это совмещать с дексрипторами) Оно родилось в качестве ответа на местный вопрос о наполнении полей объекта)))) Можете пример свой подкинуть покрутить?

Comment: @nomnoms12 работают через банальный setattr(self, ...) но лучше взять что-то типа `@dataclass` (если версия питона позволяет)

Comment: @AndyPavlov https://pastebin.com/RLwH05cj

Comment: @vitidev Не получается :( Не подскажете тогда, что я делаю не так?: https://pastebin.com/AAyHCTBh

Comment: @nomnoms12 setattr это для варианта с *args/**kwargs

Comment: @insolor Я думал что такой способ реализации не совсем верный, решил узнать, возможно есть более правильные и удобные варианты. За ответ спасибо :)

Comment: @SoGorich проще разве что dataclasses использовать или pydantic, но в любом случае будет одна строка на одно поле, и это не будет дублированием кода.

Comment: @Insolor Благодарю.